# Hot tub and A/C on one circuit?

Tags: electrical, hvac, hot-tub

Currently the house does not have air conditioning, and the wife has been hinting at adding some A/C for at least the master bedroom.

We have a hot tub off the master bedroom with what looks like a 50 amp circuit and of course it’s located on the opposite side of the house from our panel.

I was thinking I would like to add a 2 zone mini split in both the bedroom and living room.

Option 1, could I pull out the hot tub and repurpose that circuit for A mini split?

Option 2 There is a shutoff next to the hot tub, could I change that to some sort of toggle switch that would have an off, A/C, or hot tub position?

Naturally the wife likes the hot tub in the winters as well. ‍♂️

Comment: Can you get us the nameplate amp rating of the hot tub please?

Comment: It’s a Jacuzzi Model J-315.  The tub is sunk into the deck so I’m trying to google amp rating. If it helps the main panel has position 34,36 labeled hot tub, both breakers are 50amp and are tied together.

Comment: There should be an access hatch to get at the hot tub's guts for servicing purposes

Comment: 120V 60 Hz @ 15A, 240V @ 30A, 40A according to Jacuzzi.  I can pull out the drill and get underneath the deck if that doesn’t work.

Comment: Yeah, a photo of the actual hot tub nameplate would be good, especially since it sounds like it has separate control and power circuits

Comment: It is likely this is possible with a break before make transfer switch.  Both are high peak current loads, so running both together is out of the question, but you can have either or.  You would definitely want to talk to your local inspection authority before you purchase anything as parts could be extremely expensive if they must be rated for water ingress and there may be concerns about position of the actual switch which it sounds like would have to be under the hot tub deck.

Comment: In some cases I've seen authorities willing to accept a contactor with remote switch in a location they would not accept an actual switch.

Comment: It seems like a damp-area-rated subpanel with two 240 volt breakers might work to replace the shutoff.

Comment: I'd be real interested in the wire type.  Most people installing a 50A circuit reach for #6 wire, but for certain wire types, #6 is good for as much as 65A.

Comment: Is it possible to add pictures?   On the hot tub is says voltage 120/240, current 12/21/30, 60hz, single phase, wires 4.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/LyYVtoc

Comment: The size of the 2 zone mini will be needed this could be a fairly small size under 20 amps and depending on the hot tub actual size and the hot tub’s rating a small panel could be installed in place of your current shutoff. I did something similar and installed lockouts on each of the breakers. On mine I used an additional breaker position for the 120v receptacle and since my mini was “in site” the panel worked out I could see the inspector thought he was going to have me but when he saw the lockouts , nema 3r panel more than 6’ and it was all good. What size is the heater? Only 1 pump?

Comment: I believe only one pump, hopefully the imjur album above will help

Comment: @Toast1927 There is an edit button at the bottom of your question to improve it or add additional information.  Try not to delete or change the nature of the question if people have already answered.  There is a button at the top of the edit window with a picture of a little picture that you can use to add a picture to the question itself.